# Start glassfish at boot in windows

Tags: windows, glassfish, startup

This must be a dumb question, but I don't see any obvious references.  How can I get glassfish to start at boot on a windows box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install GlassFish as a service that starts automatically:

- Check out [How do I run GlassFish as a Windows service?](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FaqRunAsWindowsService) in the GlassFish Wiki for GlassFish v2.
- Use the [Platform Services Support](http://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/platform_services_available_in_v3) for GlassFish v3 (more on this in [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421013) just in case).

PS: It's often preferable to mention the version you are using...